# render form item of type text_format in twig file

Tags: theming, 8, forms

I have created a form element, basically I want text formats to change texts as accordingly.

```
$form['thankyou'] = [
        '#type' => 'text_format',
        '#title' => $this->t('Thank you'),
        '#format'=> 'full_html',
        '#default_value' => $config->get('thankyou'),
      ];
```

Now, I have created a function, where I'm getting this form element value.

```
$config = \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('myconfig');
 $thankyou_paid = $config->get('thankyou');
```

If I directly debug `$thankyou_paid`, I get all my data formatted. (in bold)

But If I render it through hook_theme,

```
return array(
      '#theme' => 'mytwig',
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#thankyou' => $thankyou_paid,
      '#cache' => ['max-age' => 0,],
    );
```

It gives me `<b>ugwdegfgiurgiuterug</b>`. Means, data gets rendered without formatting.

How to get this text (ugwdegfgiurgiuterug) as **ugwdegfgiurgiuterug**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's unsafe to use the [raw filter](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/filters-modifying-variables-in-twig-templates), better use the render element

> **raw**
>
> This filter should be avoided whenever possible, particularly if you're outputting data that could be user-entered. See [this page](https://www.drupal.org/node/2296163)
>   for more information on auto-escape in Drupal 8.

`processed_text`:

```
return [
  '#theme' => 'mytwig',
  '#thankyou' => [
    '#type' => 'processed_text',
    '#text' => $thankyou_paid,
    '#format' => 'full_html',
  ],
];
```

To configure the text format visit */admin/config/content/formats* and read the warnings

> **Improper text format configuration is a security risk.**

In this case it might be better to use *Restricted HTML* or *Basic HTML*.

Answer (score -3):

solution in twig file:

**{{  element['#thankyou']|raw }}**

raw provides formatted text.

Comment: No, the insecure `raw` filter enables unchecked user input to cause xss vulnerabilities.